# Merging a json response into an already initialized object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two different objects but they have some common properties. Both are filled with some values. I want to assign X object's values to override Y's property values if they have the same key in both object, else do nothing but y's empty prop keys should be remain.

I can achieve this purpose with some custom mapping operations but is there a simple way to do it in javascript?

```
var x = {
  name: 'John',
  addressInformation: null
}

var y = {
  name: '',
  paymentInformation: {
    iban: '12313123',
    cardNumber: '1231231231'
  },
  addressInformation: {
    city: 'Berlin'
  }
}
```

Merged object should be in my scenario:

```
y = {
  name 'John',
  paymentInformation: {
    iban: '12313123',
    cardNumber: '1231231231'
  },
  addressInformation: {
    city: 'Berlin'
  }
}
```

(I only shared the simplified version of that objects. There are many more properties)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? All you have really shown is a requirement but no attempts shown to achieve that goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) will do the job.

```js
const newObject = Object.assign(y, x);
const newObject = {
  ...y,
  ...x
}
```

Also, what [aweebit said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68703398/554021) is important.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that, whereas `{ ...y, ...x }` leaves `y` *intact* and merges `y` and `x` into a *new object* which is assigned to the variable `newObject`, `Object.assign(y, x)` *mutates* `y` and returns it without creating a new object, so `newObject === y` evaluates to `true` after calling it.

I would post this as a comment to Baruch's answer but I do not have enough reputation yet, so your upvotes are appreciated :)